# Symfony install not working in docker container

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose, composer-php

I ran into some issue with symfony install within docker. I would like to create a docker image, that automaticly install symfony and runs it. I'm using `docker-compose`. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

networks:
   nginx-php81-mysql8-node:

services:
   # nginx
   nginx-service:
      image: nginx:stable-alpine
      container_name: nginx-container
      ports:
         - "8080:80"
      volumes:
         - ./app:/var/www/html
         - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      depends_on:
         - php81-service
         - mysql8-service

   # php
   php81-service:
      build:
         context: .
         dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
      container_name: php81-container
      ports:
         - "8000:8000"
      volumes:
         - ./app:/var/www/html
         - ./docker/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
         - ./docker/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev g++ git libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
RUN mv /root/.symfony5/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony

RUN composer create-project symfony/skeleton:^6.3 .

RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN touch /var/log/xdebug.log && \
    chmod 777 /var/log/xdebug.log
```

The problem is, when my image is building, I can see that is creating the symfony project, I can't see any error in the process. But, when I enter the container, my `/var/www/html` folder is empty, there should be the files of the symfony project.

**EDIT**

Okey now I know what is the problem. Because I mount my local `app` folder to the container it is empty. When I run the container, my empty folder has benne mounted.

So, is there a way to install symfony inside the container and the same time map the folder to my local folder?

Comment: What do you mean by it wasn't working? Is there an error before the composer command? Did you tried to use a full path instead of a relative one? In any case, you cannot create a project in an non-empty directory.

Comment: I cannot see any error while the containers are building. The html folder is empty after the `composer create-project symfony/skeleton:^6.3 .` command. But If I step into the container, and manually run the `create-project` command in the `html` directory it is installed, and the symfony files are there.

Comment: There is no point in creating anything in `/var/www/html` during the image build when you're simply mounting `./app` over it when running the container. The volume is mounted _over_ the dir in the image, nothing is merged.

Comment: I just want to run everything inside my container. Or should I just run the symfony installer outside of the container, in the `./app` directory?

Comment: "but it wasnt working" - what does that mean? Is this a PHP problem, a Symfony problem, a Composer problem, or a Docker problem? PLease add all calrification **to your question** by editing it

Comment: I've updated it.

Comment: I found out, that in the `php81-service` configuration the volume `./app:/var/www/html/symfony` is causing the problem. If I remove this volume, my `html` folder is not empty there are the symfony files. But I cannot see them in my local machine, only in the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with understanding the difference between **Build Time** and **Run Time**.

Your Dockerfile is a set of instructions that dictates your Image **build**. Volumes get mounted when your Container **runs**.

You're installing your files into your Image's working directory, and then when you run your image, you're mounting an empty folder into that same directory, leading to.... an empty project.

A good example on how to get around this is to look at how some popular applications set up the installation process for their images at run time. They typically do this by creating an Entrypoint Script (which runs when the containers start), checking for the existence of certain key files, and then copying over the sources from a different directory into the working directory.

Here's an example of how Wordpress does it: https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/tree/master/latest/php8.2/fpm-alpine

At build time, they install the code into `/usr/src/wordpress` from their own repository: https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/latest/php8.2/fpm-alpine/Dockerfile#L100

```
RUN set -eux; \
    version='6.4.1'; \
    sha1='35e62d935d6a93097366476e389752dd55d8a077'; \
    \
    curl -o wordpress.tar.gz -fL "https://wordpress.org/wordpress-$version.tar.gz"; \
    echo "$sha1 *wordpress.tar.gz" | sha1sum -c -; \
    \
# upstream tarballs include ./wordpress/ so this gives us /usr/src/wordpress
    tar -xzf wordpress.tar.gz -C /usr/src/; \
    rm wordpress.tar.gz; \
    \
# https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/
    [ ! -e /usr/src/wordpress/.htaccess ]; \
    { \
        echo '# BEGIN WordPress'; \
        echo ''; \
        echo 'RewriteEngine On'; \
        echo 'RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]'; \
        echo 'RewriteBase /'; \
        echo 'RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]'; \
        echo 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f'; \
        echo 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d'; \
        echo 'RewriteRule . /index.php [L]'; \
        echo ''; \
        echo '# END WordPress'; \
    } > /usr/src/wordpress/.htaccess; \
    \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/src/wordpress; \
# pre-create wp-content (and single-level children) for folks who want to bind-mount themes, etc so permissions are pre-created properly instead of root:root
# wp-content/cache: https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/534#issuecomment-705733507
    mkdir wp-content; \
    for dir in /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/*/ cache; do \
        dir="$(basename "${dir%/}")"; \
        mkdir "wp-content/$dir"; \
    done; \
    chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content; \
    chmod -R 1777 wp-content
```

Then in their Entrypoint, they check for certain files and folders. If they don't exist, they copy them into `/var/www/html`: https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/latest/php8.2/fpm-alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh#L34

```
echo >&2 "WordPress not found in $PWD - copying now..."
        if [ -n "$(find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -name wp-content)" ]; then
            echo >&2 "WARNING: $PWD is not empty! (copying anyhow)"
        fi
        sourceTarArgs=(
            --create
            --file -
            --directory /usr/src/wordpress
            --owner "$user" --group "$group"
        )
        targetTarArgs=(
            --extract
            --file -
        )
        if [ "$uid" != '0' ]; then
            # avoid "tar: .: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted" and "tar: .: Cannot change mode to rwxr-xr-x: Operation not permitted"
            targetTarArgs+=( --no-overwrite-dir )
        fi
        # loop over "pluggable" content in the source, and if it already exists in the destination, skip it
        # https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/506 ("wp-content" persisted, "akismet" updated, WordPress container restarted/recreated, "akismet" downgraded)
        for contentPath in \
            /usr/src/wordpress/.htaccess \
            /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/*/*/ \
        ; do
            contentPath="${contentPath%/}"
            [ -e "$contentPath" ] || continue
            contentPath="${contentPath#/usr/src/wordpress/}" # "wp-content/plugins/akismet", etc.
            if [ -e "$PWD/$contentPath" ]; then
                echo >&2 "WARNING: '$PWD/$contentPath' exists! (not copying the WordPress version)"
                sourceTarArgs+=( --exclude "./$contentPath" )
            fi
        done
        tar "${sourceTarArgs[@]}" . | tar "${targetTarArgs[@]}"
        echo >&2 "Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to $PWD"
```

**tl;dr;** Use [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)s to assist in handling your runtime needs inside your build.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is create the symfony project outside the docker container, and then in your docker-compose mount the volume, specifying where is your symfony project and where you want to mount it inside de docker container.

```
 volumes:
     - ./symfony-path-host:/var/www/html
```

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Yes, that one way to do it. But I would like to install symfony inside the container.